# no versions of com.onesignal:OneSignal are available grade error

Tags: android, onesignal

I am getting the following error our of no where

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any matches for com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1,3.99.99] as no versions of com.onesignal:OneSignal are available.
```

I can not figure out why this would be happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my entire gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.11.0, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "-----"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 65
        versionName "1.0.65"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: '-----',
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had this issue too.
I changed version to just 3.1.9 like below and everything worked fine. 
I mean like this:

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1'
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that after I posted this and never updated it. Thanks. Hopefully this helps othera

Answer (score 2):

change the line as like this

```
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

for me work also! thanks

INFO: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.